# Target a div based on your variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem targeting a class with my project.

I got this small variable who targeting the number on the ahref

```
var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
```

and with this I created

```
$('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(200).addClass('open');
```

But I want to use the outcome of that to target a paragraph tag inside that specefic div from:

```
('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue)"
```

But I have no idea how to target the pargraph, I thought something like this:

```
('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue 'p')
```

but saldy it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `$('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue + ' p')`